# Why does my computer crash every time I enter rendered mode?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, hardware

I work on a relatively old iMac (2015) and every time I enter rendered view in Cycles, the Mac just freezes. The mouse wont move and the keyboard is unresponsive. The scene isn't even that complicated, just a few simple shapes with a principled shader. And before today, Blender 2.8/9 had never had this problem. The CPU is a 2.8 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5 and I only use CPU rendering as I don’t have a GPU. Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: The lack of a GPU  (or more likely an integrated one) is probably the cause of your issue. Blender 2.8 and above requires a GPU that supports OpenGL 3.3. Try using Blender 2.79 (The interface is a bit less "pretty", and there is no EEVEE, but Cycles is still there and should work)

Comment: same as above your mac wont support opengl 3.3, my best advice is that you buy a new hardware intel or amd cpu, but never use macs for rendering/texturing, modelling and else stuff...

Comment: Recommend try any linux distro on your imac and see whether that works.